# TCPDF Page Margin Issue

Tags: php, margin, tcpdf, margins

I'm creating PDF files with PHP using TCPDF. I have a small problem with created PDF files.
I would like to set up right and left margin of each PDF file created. Currently if there is 10px margin on the left side, there is 20px margin on the right side.

How do I set up right and left page margin?

Thank you all for your time and concern.

I tried following;

`$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, -50, true);` and `$pdf->SetRightMargin(-50);` without any luck.

Comment: I guess I have found the documentation for it. http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#ab3bbdb7c85ea08d175fd559be6132ba0. Unfortunately didn't do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? I don't want to suggest things you've already been over and would also like to make sure you were doing it correctly.

Comment: I edited my question cillosis. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the [new documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ab3bbdb7c85ea08d175fd559be6132ba0) it shows the function as

`TCPDF::SetMargins($left,$top,$right = -1,$keepmargins = false)`

And describes the parameters as:

> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> $left   (float) Left margin.
> $top    (float) Top margin.
> $right  (float) Right margin. Default value is the left one.
> $keepmargins    (boolean) if true overwrites the default page margins
> ```

So, for the right margin a `-1` is used to indicate that no right margin was supplied and to use the same as the left margin. You were using `-50` which is not a valid margin.

Try this instead:

```
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought we could define integers depending on PDF_UNIT constant while instantiating TCPDF class. Unfortunately their documentation is not well prepared / organized.

Comment: This still doesn't work in their new version.. seems like nothing is able to set right margin (or at least setting it to 0).. definitely works for top and left margin.